# How to Mount this SD card?

Tags: mount, sd-card

I get in Discs

[image]

I looked in OS X that it is 16 bit formatted but it should have been 32fat but it is not. There is Raspbian which does not work correctly. 
I want to format the disc to fat32. 
Pressing the icon there will show all action buttons inactive so I cannot format it now without doing something which I think should possible be mounting somehow.

---

How can you mount the sd card such that I can format it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gparted. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Once that's done, run Gparted by searching for it in Dash (~Start Menu). Let Gparted scan your drives, and select the SD card from the dropdown menu near the top right of the Gparted window (most likely `sdb`).

Right click the partition listed and hover over the `Format...` option. Choose the `FAT32` option from the list. Click the green check mark button at the top of the Gparted window to apply the format.

Remember, this does erase anything you have on the SD card.

If you are unsure about anything, comment and I'll help out.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command: mount  
`mount /dev/Sdx /mnt`

*You can't format a partition while it is mounted